# PropertyFieldCollectionData control Panel customization

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, pnp

Is it possible to edit  **No data in your collection** text in the panel? See the image below.

I need to change the text depends on the user language.

I am able to change the text in Save and cancel button but  I couldn't find the correspondent props of `PropertyFieldCollectionData`.

[image]

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of `PropertyFieldCollectionData` control, there is no configurable property available to show the custom message when there is no data in your collection.

**Documentation**: [PropertyFieldCollectionData control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldCollectionData/)

---

As per the source code of this control, this message is controlled by `{strings.CollectionDataEmptyValue}`

```
{
  (!this.state.crntItems || this.state.crntItems.length === 0) && (
    <p className={`PropertyFieldCollectionData__panel__no-collection-data ${styles.noCollectionData}`}>{strings.CollectionDataEmptyValue}</p>
  )
}
```

**Reference**: [CollectionDataViewer.tsx](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/blob/338afac2247e975dda72e5e98b643c49ed8f8486/src/propertyFields/collectionData/collectionDataViewer/CollectionDataViewer.tsx)

Which is controlled by localized strings imported in code like:

```
import * as strings from 'PropertyControlStrings';
```

This `PropertyControlStrings` is defined in [mystrings.d.ts](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/blob/31db37539b6e84c5e6d4e2f174804ae877bc8983/src/loc/mystrings.d.ts):

```
declare module 'PropertyControlStrings' {
  const strings: IPropertyControlStrings;
  export = strings;
}
```

---

So, you have to use the localized values for the property `CollectionDataEmptyValue`. You will find this property & value with different languages in localization folder (check by opening each file in below folder):

[sp-dev-fx-property-controls/src/loc](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/tree/31db37539b6e84c5e6d4e2f174804ae877bc8983/src/loc)

---

Try making below changes once you install `@pnp/spfx-property-controls` package:

> Once the package is installed, you will have to configure the resource file of the property controls to be used in your project. You can do this by opening the `config/config.json` and adding the following line to the `localizedResources` property:

```
"PropertyControlStrings": "./node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls/lib/loc/{locale}.js"
```

**Reference**: [Getting started - Configuration](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/#configuration)

**Related Microsoft documentation**: [Localize SharePoint Framework client-side web parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/localize-web-parts)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will try and let you know if that works.